# Using PCA on linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I want to use principal component analysis to reduce some noise before applying linear regression.

I have 1000 samples and 200 features

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

X = np.random.rand(1000,200)
y = np.random.rand(1000,1)
```

With this data I can train my model:

```
model.fit(X,y)
```

But if I try the same after applying PCA

```
pca = PCA(n_components=8)
pca.fit(X)
PCA(copy=True, iterated_power='auto', n_components=3, random_state=None,
  svd_solver='auto', tol=0.0, whiten=False)
principal_components =  pca.components_

model.fit(principal_components,y)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [8, 1000]
```

Comment: Are you sure PCA is what you want for noise reduction? Noise typically increases variance, and PCA-based dimensionality reduction might be dropping the least noisy data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=8)
X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X)

model.fit(X_pca,y)
```

That is, you simultaneously fit PCA to X and transform it into (1000, 8) array named X_pca. That's what you should use instead of the pca.components_

Comment: from the documentation, "Principal axes in feature space, representing the directions of maximum variance in the data." I usually think of it as profiles relating the original dimensionality to the new one.