# How generate predictions after doing PCA in Python

Tags: python, pca

If I have a training set `trainX`, `trainy`, I know that you can run PCA with

```
pca = PCA(n_components=5)
Xred = pca.fit(trainX).transform(trainX)
```

If I want to run a model, say Linear Regression, do I then run PCA on the `testX`?

Like this:

```
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(trainX, trainY)
testXred = pca.fit(testX).transform(testX)
predictions = clf.predict(testXred)
```

Or do I only run PCA on the training set, so the Linear Regression prediction should be this instead?

```
predictions = clf.predict(testX)
```

or this?

```
testXred = pca.fit(trainX).transform(testX)
predictions = clf.predict(testXred)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to reduce noise using PCA before doing the linear regression, here's an example, which might help:
[Using PCA on linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41866841/using-pca-on-linear-regression)

Comment: That only shows running `pca.fit_transform` on `X`. Do you also need to run `pca.fit_transform` on `X_test`?